# Redirecting user to another view if not logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on a user management functionality right now. I am trying to add authorization and redirect user to my login page if he is trying to access the user management page like this before logging in:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult UsersList()
{
    if (Session["UserName"] == null)
    {
        RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    }
    else
    {
        var User = new User();
        User.usersList = DBManager.Instance.GetUsersList();
        User.PreferedLanguages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "ENGLISH", Selected = true, Value = "ENGLISH" });
        User.PreferedLanguages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DUTCH", Value = "DUTCH" });
        return View(User);
    }
}
```

But I should return a view for an action result right? This code doesn't compile and I get the following error :

> Error 4   'WebApplication9.Controllers.UserManagementController.UsersList()':
>   not all code paths return a value >E:\Work\WebApplication9\Controllers\UserManagementController.cs

At this point is it possible to return another controllers view?

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");` (your missing the `return`)

Comment: Are you doing it in all of your action methods? You should implement some sort of authentication (_i.e. formas authentication_) and use `[Authorize]` attribute to handle everything for you.

Comment: @AdilMammadov : is it available for asp.net mvc? I am new to this. So thought of doing it by keeping the username with Session.

Comment: @ViVi check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578374/AplusBeginner-splusTutorialplusonplusCustomplusF

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov : Thanks for the link. I think the best way is to go the `[Authorize]` way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the following code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
```

instead of simple `RedirectToAction`.

`ActionResult` is set of instructions, which will be performed by a action invoker after action will be completed. `RedirectToActionResult` (the return type of `RedirectToAction`) contains instructions which should be written to `Response` for performing correct redirect.

As far as I understood, this is how action invoking works, maybe official documentation has another opinion about this.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Already corrected it as per Stephen Muecke's comment

Comment: @ViVi you're welcome, it is sad, but my answer was a bit later then Stephen Muecke's comment